# String cannot be converted into JSON in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, string, object, parsing

```
self.str = "
{"queryString":"user=test&password=1 OR TRUE ; -- ' OR TRUE; -- OR TRUE; K2FUZZ " OR TRUE; -- OR TRUE; K2FUZZ '","clientIP":"127.0.0.1","clientPort":"43470","dataTruncated":false,"contentType":"","requestURI":"/DemoApplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/UserCheck3","generationTime":0,"body":"","method":"GET","url":"/DemoApplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/UserCheck3?user=test&password=test123"}
"

self.obj = JSON.parse(self.str);
```

I am getting error:

**base.js:1 SyntaxError: Unexpected token O in JSON at position 82
at JSON.parse ()**

I tried various methods but nothing works. Can anyone tell me why this error is occurring and how can I fix it?

Just for the context, self.str contains a string value that I have obtained from an API response.

Comment: As you can see on the "wrong" error message (by clicking on "Run code in snippet") your example is not a [mcve] -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Andreas Here I am not trying to post my code rather I am just trying to give a rough example of what my string is

Comment: @Andreas I did go through what you said, I cannot post the whole code because it is of no use. I provided you with a sample input and what I am trying to do with the input and what error I got. There is no need to be this much rude mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you work on this backwards - by creating an object and stringifying it - you can see that the quotes in `queryString` need to be *escaped*. You can then turn it into valid JSON.

So, whatever data this JSON is coming from needs to be properly formatted because it's *not* valid JSON at the moment.

```js
const obj = {
  "queryString": "user=test&password=1 OR TRUE ; -- \' OR TRUE; -- OR TRUE; K2FUZZ \"OR TRUE;--OR TRUE;K2FUZZ\'",
  "clientIP": "127.0.0.1",
  "clientPort": "43470",
  "dataTruncated": false,
  "contentType": "",
  "requestURI": "/DemoApplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/UserCheck3",
  "generationTime": 0,
  "body": "",
  "method": "GET",
  "url": "/DemoApplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/UserCheck3?user=test&password=test123"
}

const str = JSON.stringify(obj);

document.querySelector('pre').textContent = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2);

// console.log(JSON.parse(str));
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to solve the issue by taking idea from your solution